# cant find files written to device

Tags: android

I am using 
    outStream = ctext.openFileOutput("demo.jpg",0);
    outStream.write(data);
    outStream.close();

If I use the emulator the file is written to the data hieracrchy on the simulated sdcard.

When I run on my Samsung 15500 I cant find where the data has been written to.  If I click on MyFiles I can see the directories under Android with a data subdir but no sign of the file.

Am I missing something either in the method of writing the file or the way to find it on the device.

Comment: Are you sure it's being written? If your phone isn't rooted (or a developer device) you don't have the permissions necessary to access the data directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to find it via `Context.getFileList();`. The docs to `Context.openFileOutput()` say

> Open a private file associated with this Context's application package for writing

So I guess there is no "guarantee" that you can have arbitrary access to it via file paths or urls or such.

Comment: Thanks for the response.    I failed to appreciate that files my app writes need to be private i.e not visible from the handset.   My code finds the files so all is working.